# Excel VBA Format cell as custom "h"

Tags: excel, vba, time, format, cell

I have a cell with a time value as 1:23:45 AM and would like to display just the hour value or use it for other calculations. Need to do this using vba. No, I cannot format the column manually.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 4):

To use VBA to format the cell to only display the hour:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    .NumberFormat = "H"
End With
```

To read the hour value in VBA (regardless of how the cell is formatted):

```
Dim hourValue As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    If (IsDate(Format(.Value, "hh:mm:ss"))) Then
        hourValue = Hour(.Value)
    Else
        // handle the error
    End If
End With
```

If you want to use the displayed value in code without performing the conversion in VBA then use the `Text` property of the cell (`Range`) rather than the `Value` property. You'll need to be sure that the cell is formatted correctly first:

```
Dim hourValue As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    If ((.NumberFormat = "H") And _
            (IsDate(Format(.Value, "hh:mm:ss")))) Then
        hourValue = CInt(.Text)
    Else
        // handle the error
    End If
End With
```

If you just want to use the hour value in a worksheet formula then use the `HOUR()` worksheet function - e.g. `=HOUR(A1)`

Finally, if you cannot format the column manually because the sheet is protected then you won't be able to format it in VBA either

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me.
Dim hourValue As Integer
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    If (IsDate(Format(.Value, "hh:mm:ss"))) Then
        hourValue = Hour(.Value)
    Else
        // handle the error
    End If
End With

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your cell is a time field or not. If it is, can you do the following?

```
dim h as integer
h = Hour(Cell(1,1))
```